# Refresh list on ListActivity Android

Tags: android, refresh, listactivity

I made and ListActivity :

```
public class Remove1 extends ListActivity{

    ArrayList<String> listaE = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> listaL = new ArrayList<String>();
    int resh=0;
    InputStream instream;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        lexo(); //Fill list from file
        String[] mStringArray = new String[listaE.size()];
        mStringArray = listaE.toArray(mStringArray);  //change list to String[] Array
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Remove1.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mStringArray)); //Fill List
    }
```

So When I click item, item is removed from list, but the list is not refreshing ?
When I finish(); and start activity again than it removes a line,, but I want to be removed instantly..

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        listaE.remove(position); //Remove Line
        listaL.remove(position); 
        write(); // write to file changes
        lexo(); // read from file changes and fill lists
    }
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try**

```
public class Remove1 extends ListActivity{

    ArrayList<String> listaE = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> listaL = new ArrayList<String>();
    int resh=0;
    InputStream instream;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        lexo(); //Fill list from file
        String[] mStringArray = new String[listaE.size()];
        mStringArray = listaE.toArray(mStringArray);  //change list to String[] Array
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Remove1.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mStringArray);
        setListAdapter(adapter); //Fill List
    }

@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        listaE.remove(position); //Remove Line
        listaL.remove(position); 
        write(); // write to file changes
        lexo(); // read from file changes and fill lists

       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: try ((ArrayAdapter<String>)l.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I see this when I write the code "Unchecked cast from ListAdapter to ArrayAdapter<String>" ,, and when I click the item, does not make changes, i must go back and come again to see changes...

Comment: try declare you adapter in class scope

Answer (score 0):

A ListView is backed by an adapter.  Your adapter is backed by a String[], from this line:

```
String[] mStringArray = new String[listaE.size()];
```

You need to remove the object from your adapter, not your list.  In your onListItemClick do this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>) l.getAdapter();
String item = (String) listaE.remove(position);
adapter.remove(item);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

If you want to remove the item from your List object, you can, just not sure of your use case. Perhaps you'd like to keep it so you can restore the ListView at some point.

Comment: in this case, the string will be removed and from array list or just from list-view ?
I need to be removed from list and from adapter

Comment: I see this when I write the code "Unchecked cast from ListAdapter to ArrayAdapter<String>" and application stops when i click on item

Comment: I'd think the error is since you remove the object from the list that backs the adapter and then the adapter tries to remove it again. Use adapter.remove(listaE.get(position)) instead.

Comment: Updated answer to remove unsafe cast.  If the app stops, please post the stacktrace, I'll help troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Remove string which corresponds with removed item of the list from `mStringArray` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on `ArrayAdapter` (you have to store it in some variable first).

Comment: can you help me how to store it on variable ? I have no clue how to do that.. :(

Comment: `ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Remove1.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mStringArray); setListAdapter(arrayAdapter)`